# Dates with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm fairly new with Python - so please be kind:) 
I have a dataframe with date column in it. I import it from TXT file with

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('FileName.TXT', low_memory=False , sep="\t", 
                  parse_dates= ['OrderDate']).
```

The dates are imported as timestamp - `YYYY-MM-DD`.

I need to transform them into `mm/dd/yyyy` format.
I have two issues:

1. I tried using all sort of methods - maybe I'm missing something because after each time when I look at the `OrderDate` column - the dates are `dd/mm/yyyy` - which is close - but not quite there.
2. Not directly related, but might help you understand what I need: 
   The end result is to have an excel file that I can upload my system. (the requirement of the system is to have dates `mm/dd/yyyy`)
   I tried one time to change the type of the date to `str`, I had it nicely formatted as needed, saw the `OrderDate` column in Anaconda as `mm/dd/yyyy`, but the excel revert it again to `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Thanks for the help:)

Comment: Sounds like your problem is exclusively with excel and how it displays dates. As long as you've gotten your dates in a format that excel can interpret as a date, how these dates are displayed in your sheet must be defined in excel itself under the "Format Cells/date" option.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('xyz.csv', sep="\t", parse_dates ['OrderDate'])
df1['OrderDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.OrderDate)
df1['OrderDate'] = df1['OrderDate'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
df1.to_excel('abcd.xls')
```

Tested with Ubuntu 19.04 and LibreOffice Calc. Working fine.
If you are facing the problem after opening your excel client, there is a chance that your excel client is changing it to DateTime automatically.
In that case, try opening with some text editor and check if it is in mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: it is displayed as mm/dd/yyyy but is it excel date or just text?

Comment: It's text. strftime() converts to text.

Comment: the point of my question was that OP will upload to a system that may expect excel date, not text. Of course it's OP that knows that. just a fair warning.

Comment: As he mentioned "I tried one time to change the type of the date to str", I assumed string would work or the system would automatically convert that to date. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Thanks guys - used some of the advises and it worked!